# Utorrent should only be active when VPN is active

Tags: windows, gratis, vpn

I am looking for a free WIndows (7) app, which will:

- auto connect to BT Guard when I log in to windows
- stop Utorrent when my VPN connection drops (not so important, as my VPN only really drops when my wifi drops)
- auto connect to BT Guard when my WiFi reconnects and restart Utorrent

Comment: Why not simply leave it running all the time since logon? It won't cause any trouble when WiFi drops since it will try to connect and fail, and any downloads/seedings will be stopped. Force closing it might risk damage its internal data files.

Comment: Yes, but when WiFi comes back up, his VPN will not & now his ISP can see his torrenting. It is the WiFi restarting that is his problem.

Comment: You might have to write your own solution. You could write a batch file that checks if your connection is active (ping your VPN for example). If the ping errors out then quit utorrent, keep on checking and once the check is positive, start up the VPN, check for IP change and if positive then start utorrent.

Comment: I will polish my Python skeelz. The problem is that there is a small (to humans, but huge to  computers) time gap where I could be tormenting if I auto-start with Windows before my script determines that I am not connected to the VPN and closes uTorrrent. During that time, my ISP can see my traffic.

Comment: @Izzy do you have the power to migrate this to http://security.stackexchange.com/ ? Maybe someone there already has a solution